# How to group and filter using crossfilter in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, crossfilter

js users,

I just started using d3.js & crossfilter and was attempting to make use of Adam Pearce's example on [meteor map](http://roadtolarissa.com/meteors/) to visualise weather data. Instead of having only one record for each name in the "name" column, I have multiple-year records as I'm keen to analyse the weather changes over the years. Below is a sample of the original data and my own data:

**orginal data**

name       mass_g    year     cartodb_id ....

Vilna       1        1967     34039

Silistra    1        1917     34017

**My data**

name           rainfall          year     cartodb_id ....

station_A      100               1997     34039

station_A      200               1998     34039

station_B      300               1997     34017

station_B      400               1998     34017

I'm not sure where went wrong as it did not produce any error(s). However,

1. the crossfilter did not seem to take effect on the map
2. it did not group the rainfall values by the stations on the map (I think they are overlapping each other)
3. I couldn't group the two bar charts such that I could show the time series of rainfall over the years, as well as the rainfall distribution (I think need to use some Reduce function but I can't figure it out)

Below is my js script to replace the original drawMap.js (sorry, it's a little too long; Thank you for any kind advice!):

```
var width = 1000,
    height = 500;

var proj = d3.geo.mercator()
        .center([103.8,1.33])
        .scale(100000)
        .rotate([0,0]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
        .projection(proj);

// for map
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate(proj.translate())
    .scale(proj.scale())
    .scaleExtent([100000,Infinity]) //.scaleExtent([height*.33, 4 * height])
    .on("zoom", zoom);


var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .call(zoom);

function zoom() {
    proj.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
    svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
    circles
        .attr("cx", function(d){return proj([d.long, d.lat])[0];})
        .attr("cy", function(d){return proj([d.long, d.lat])[1];});
}

var borders = svg.append("g");

var impacts = svg.append("g");

// colours and scales for the corresponding values in map

var metorScale = d3.scale.pow().exponent(.5).domain([0, 100, 1000, 2000, 3000, 5000, 8000]);

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([1980, 1888, 1996, 2004, 2014]);

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 1e-6)
    .style("background", "rgba(250,250,250,.7)");

tooltip.append("img")
    .attr("id", "tooltipImg")
    .attr("height", 200)
    .attr("width", 200)
    .style("opacity", "1");

// change the fell file to our rainfall
// file has to be at aggregated level for each year
// one station one value for one year
// change the json file to our map
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "Planning_Area_Census2010_WGS84.json") 
    .defer(d3.csv, "yearlyrainfall.csv")
    /*.defer(d3.json, "pics.json")*/
    .await(ready);

var metors;

// for the rest of the code
// removed pics in the inputs
function ready(error, topology, csv){
    borders.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.Planning_Area_Census2010_WGS84)
                .geometries)
    .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "border")

    rawMetors = csv;


  // change mass_g to rainfall
  // cartodb_id is a key for our station

    metors = [];
    rawMetors.forEach(function(d){
        d.rainfall = +d.rainfall;
        d.year = +d.year;
        d.id = +d.cartodb_id;
        d.name = d.name;
        d.region = d.region;
        metors.push(d);  

    });
    metors.sort(function(a, b){return a.id - b.id;})

  // size tag to rainfall
  //colour tag to year
    metorScale
        .range([1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10]);

    colorScale
        .range(["#FFFF66", "#FFFF00", "#E68000", "#D94000", "#CC0000"]);

    circles = impacts.selectAll("circle")
        .data(metors).enter()
            .append("svg:a")
                .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.database; })
                .attr("xlink:show", "new")
            .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d){return proj([d.long, d.lat])[0];})
                .attr("cy", function(d){return proj([d.long, d.lat])[1];})
                .attr("r",  function(d){return metorScale(d.rainfall);})
                .attr("id", function(d){return "id" + d.id;})
                .style("fill", function(d){return colorScale(d.year);   })
        .on("mouseover", function(d){
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                .attr("fill-opacity", 1);

            tooltip
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 5) + "px")
                .transition().duration(300)
                .style("opacity", 1)
                .style("display", "block")

            updateDetails(d);
            })
        .on("mouseout", function(d){
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("stroke", "")
                .attr("fill-opacity", function(d){return 1;})

            tooltip.transition().duration(700).style("opacity", 0);
        });


    metorsCF = crossfilter(metors),
        all = metorsCF.groupAll(),

        year = metorsCF.dimension(function(d){return d.year;}), /*creating a type dimension*/
        years = year.group(function(d){return Math.floor(d);}),

        rainfall = metorsCF.dimension(function(d){return d.rainfall }), /*creating a type dimension*/
        rainfalls = rainfall.group(function(d){return Math.floor(d/10)*10;}),   

    // for grouping at var charts

    // group by type, change to region  
      region = metorsCF.dimension(function(d){return d.region;}), /*creating a type dimension*/
      regions = region.group();

    // create group of ids
         cartoDbId = metorsCF.dimension(function(d){return d.id;}); /*creating a type dimension*/
         cartoDbIds = cartoDbId.group()




  // create all the bar charts

  // first one draw by group of years

    // change the domain relate to the format tick in barchart.js
    var charts = [
        barChart()
                .dimension(year)
                .group(years)
            .x(d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([1970,2020])
                .rangeRound([-1, 20*24-5])),

    // change the domain relate to the format tickvalues in barchart.js
        barChart()
                .dimension(rainfall)
                .group(rainfalls)
            .x(d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([1,10000])
                .rangeRound([0,20*24]))
    ];

    var chart = d3.selectAll(".chart")
            .data(charts)
            .each(function(chart){chart.on("brush", renderAll).on("brushend", renderAll)});

    d3.selectAll("#total")
            .text(metorsCF.size());


    function render(method){
        d3.select(this).call(method);
    }


    lastFilterArray = [];
    metors.forEach(function(d, i){
        lastFilterArray[i] = 1;
    });

    function renderAll(){
        chart.each(render);

        var filterArray = cartoDbIds.all();
        filterArray.forEach(function(d, i){
            if (d.value != lastFilterArray[i]){
                lastFilterArray[i] = d.value;
                d3.select("#id" + d.key).transition().duration(500)
                        .attr("r", d.value == 1 ? 2*metorScale(metors[i].rainfall) : 0)
                    .transition().delay(550).duration(500)
                        .attr("r", d.value == 1 ? metorScale(metors[i].rainfall) : 0);

            }
        })

        d3.select("#active").text(all.value());
    }

    window.reset = function(i){
        charts[i].filter(null);
        renderAll();
    }

    renderAll();
}


// to show the labels on what to display on map
 var printDetails = [
                    {'var': 'name', 'print': 'Station'},
                    {'var': 'region', 'print': 'Region'},
                    {'var': 'rainfall', 'print': 'Rainfall(mm)'},
                    {'var': 'year', 'print': 'Year'}];




function updateDetails(metorsCF){
//  var image = new Image();
//  image.onload = function(){
//      document.getElementById("tooltipImg").src = 'pictures/' + metor.cartodb_id + '.jpg';}
//  image.src = 'pictures/' + metor.cartodb_id + '.jpg';

    tooltip.selectAll("div").remove();
    tooltip.selectAll("div").data(printDetails).enter() 
        .append("div")
            .append('span')
                .text(function(d){return d.print + ": ";})              
                .attr("class", "boldDetail")
            .insert('span')
                .text(function(d){return metorsCF[d.var];})
                .attr("class", "normalDetail");
}

  [1]: http://roadtolarissa.com/meteors/
```

Comment: Do you think you could create a codepen or jsFiddle for this? Would be a lot easier to analyze the issue that way. Cheers!

Comment: Agreed. Either convert this to a snippet, or (easier) a jsFiddle. I think I know what I need to do and I'll be back in a few minutes with a link.

Comment: Here is a fantastic example of what you can do with filtering and (if I'm not mistaken), it should work for you. http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have created (my first) jsFriddle. I'm not sure how to put in the Json file and the csv data but have described my csv data in it. http://jsfiddle.net/NicholasSham/00jcqmg1/4/ @AlexeyAyzin sorry I wasn't clear enough. My intention for the bar charts was (1. to sum the rainfall from all stations yearly and generate a yearly bar chat; 2. to create rainfall distribution for the other bar chart)

Comment: I made some progress! I managed to solve the bar charts. Now my program is the map circles doesn't interact with the two bar charts. How to display the total rainfall for the station, correspond to the crossfilter selection in the two bar charts?